# MC3100 Scanner Programming

Tags: lazarus, motorola

We are using Motorola MC3100 Mobile Computer, Barcode scanners. running Windows CE6.0

To program these we intend to use Lazarus/FPC and indeed we have produced a test app that works on the device.

Our problem is that we do not know how to access/activate the scanner engine so that the scanner activates and returns the value of the scanned barcode.

We are aware of a SDK from Motorola which works only with Visual Studio 2008, but of course this would require purchase then development time in a completely new environment.

We thought that there may exist a DLL library that will allow us to perform the function we need but so far, after a lot of looking, we have not had any luck.

Anyone had any experience with this (or similar) or have any tips for us to research further. We are now at a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the links. Hopefully one of them will help.

- http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/SymScan (methods Open, Execute, Close)
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus-ccr/files/SymScan
- http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,3771.msg31511.html#msg31511
- http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,8505.msg41027.html#msg41027
- http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Handhelds_-_PDAs/Windows_Mobile/Q_27037964.html
- http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=13450&sliceId=&dialogID=426652298&stateId=1%200%20426650198
- http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=313028
- [www.google.rs/search?q="SCNAPI32.DLL"+functions](http://www.google.rs/search?q=%22SCNAPI32.DLL%22%20functions)